# Async Await No me funciona en Objeto

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, async-await

disculpen tengo un objeto con varios métodos, y solo unos pocos estan llamando una api, y bueno tengo un método calShippingCost que no me esta traendo la data de la api, opte por mejor usar el async await en el método calShippingCost para q me traiga la data de la api, pero no me esta funcionando, agradeceria mucho q alguien me pueda apoyar, ¡Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: error]

```
calcShippingCost: async function(){
        const sellerId = document.querySelector('.seller .tool_tip')?.getAttribute('data-seller')
        const skuId = document.querySelector('p.numSku span')?.textContent
        const ubicacion = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ubicacion'))?.postalcode

            console.log('estoy dentro de la Función calcShippingCost',sellerId,skuId,ubicacion)
        if(sellerId && skuId && ubicacion){
            console.log('estoy dentro de If de calcShippingCost')
            const apiSimulation = await fetch('/api/checkout/pub/orderForms/simulation',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    items: [{
                        id: skuId,
                        quantity: 1,
                        seller: sellerId,
                    }],
                    country: 'PER',
                    postalCode: ubicacion
                })
            })
            // let hshsh = await apiSimulation.json()
          
            // .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
            let r = await apiSimulation.json()
            console.log(r)
            // .then(data => console.log('Prueba calcShippingCost',data))
            // .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }`
```

Comment: El `console.log` muestra que tu variable `sellerId` es `undefined`. Por ello no se ejecuta la llamada a `fetch`.

Comment: Si asi es, pero no entiendo porque pasa eso, al parecer no esta capturando con querySelector, pero hay otros métodos que si estan siendo llamados y funcionan

Comment: Entonces el error no es *Async Await no me funciona*, el error es otro. Intenta depurar bien tus variables, verifica que el elemento que estás tratando de leer realmente tiene el atributo que le indicas (`data-seller`).

Comment: Evita usar capturas de pantalla para mostrar código o mensajes de error, es mejor el texto sin más. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el HTML ligado a tu código JS, pues como te ha hecho ver @MauricioContreras el `undefined` viene porque no estás refiriéndote correctamente a los elementos en el `querySelector`, por cierto, veo que tienes un `?` antes de `getAttribute()`
, ¿qué significa eso?

Comment: ese signo ? significa q si el querySelector no me trae nada, no me lanzé un console.error() sino algo como undefined

Comment: @A.Cedano el operador `?.` es conocido como el [operador de encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Saludos